# Time varying copula vs. dynamic copula

Tags: copula, time-varying-covariate

I need to understand the difference between *time varying copula* ([Patton, 2006](http://public.econ.duke.edu/~ap172/Patton_IER_2006.pdf)) and *dynamic copula*.

- For the time varying copula, is it when the parameters of copula follow ARMA($p$,$q$)?
- Is that when the marginals are modeled by GARCH or ARMA, so the copula will be dynamic?

**References**

- Patton, Andrew J. ["Modelling asymmetric exchange rate dependence*."](http://public.econ.duke.edu/~ap172/Patton_IER_2006.pdf) *International economic review* 47.2 (2006): 527-556.
- Engle, Robert. ["Dynamic conditional correlation: A simple class of multivariate generalized autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity models."](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/073500102288618487#.VxUiCvl974Y) *Journal of Business & Economic Statistics* 20.3 (2002): 339-350.

Comment: Could you give references for *time-varying copula* and *dynamic copula*?

Comment: MODELLING ASYMMETRIC EXCHANGE RATE DEPENDENCE  Patton(2006)

Comment: I cannot see *dynamic copula* mentioned in Patton (2006)... Do you have a reference for *dynamic copula*?

Comment: R.F. Engle, Dynamic conditional correlation: a simple class of multivariateGARCHmodels

Answer (score 2):

Time-varying copula and dynamic copulas are the same. The parameters of time-varying Copula are not constant meaning that every parameter has a dynamic equation.

Comment: Could you provide any reference to support your statement?

Comment: There are many .. take a look on this article http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2556623 .. precisely, first note page 17 .. the authors use Manthos Vogiatzoglou's toolbox to calculate time-varying (dynamic) copulas

Comment: Is the reason why the ARMA-GARCH model is called *time-varying*, whereas ARIMA model is said to be based on *constant copula* only due to the former possessing a GARCH component?